# How do I set Xml serialization attributes per instance (or per type) with generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, attributes, xml-serialization

I have a class (more complex, but simplified for the example) like this:

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass() { }

   [XmlAttribute("somename")]
   public String MyString { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("AString")]
   public List<String> TheList { get; set; }

   // Other uninteresting methods and private members.
}
```

Xml Serialization works fine.  What I'd like to do (if it isn't too crazy) is change this class to use generics so that I can have "TheList" use different types.  What I want is for the XmlElement name to be able to be specified per instance (or per type) somehow.

Ideal would be something where the name is set when the instance is created.  It would be nice to macro replace the attribute parameter strings on creation, but I have no idea if anything similar is possible.  Maybe it would look something like:

```
public class MyClass<T, (MagicalMacro)> {
   // Some kind of constructor, methods, whatever as needed.
   // MyString as above.

   [XmlElement(MagicalMacro)] // This does not compile.
   public List<T> TheList { get; set; }

   // Etc.
}
...
MyClass<int, (MagicalMacro)> myClass = new MyClass<int, "AnInteger">();
```

Less ideal but still satisfactory would be to name the "TheList" output name based on the type of T.

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   // Same constructor and MyString as the first example.

   [XmlElement(typeof(T).Name)] // This does not compile - string not constant.
   public List<T> TheList { get; set; }

   // Etc.
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes need literals. The way to approach this is by using `XmlAttributeOverrides` to configure it *at runtime*, and pass that to the `XmlSerializer` constructor. However: cache and re-use the serializer instances when you do this, or you will leak dynamically generated assemblies.

Comment: The thing that confuses me about the need to do so at runtime is that I have all the information I need at compile-time.  I can use a literal, I just need to set it to be different based on the type of the generic being used.  It seems very inelegant to duplicate everything in a class except for the "XmlElement" attribute for each new type that might be used.  This breaks the usefulness of generics.

Comment: @Steven - on the contrary - the point of generics is that you do *the same thing* per T, not specialise per T. And by literal, I meant *constant* literal, not an expression that *resolves* to a value that happens to come from a literal.

Comment: @Steven if you find attributes too limited, you can always do the XAO setup and serializer-cache via generics and typeof(T)

Comment: It seems to me that specializing how something serializes to xml based on its type would be very common, even though it's only changing xml tags.  The code is the same, exactly, for the different types - only the attribute needs to change.  I've now got 10 different classes, filled with exactly the same code, except for 1 attribute per file and a nightmare managing type consistency throughout.  If I try to be clever, I might move _some_ of the code to a base class, but I still have 10 types just so I can specify a different xml tag.  XmlAttributeOverrides have not been working for me.

Comment: @Steven it should... I'm busy currently (and it isnt a trivial example), but I might take a peek to see I it can be done.

Comment: So @MarcGravell did you eventually sort this out?  I will be curious to know how you went about it.